# Global namespace is not checked in other namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm trying to use namespaces in my code so I have a header file that looks like this :

```
#include <string>

namespace AppNamespace
{
  class A
  {
    std::string name;
  };
}
```

When I try to compile this, it says "'string' is not a member of AppNamespace::std". If I remove the `std::` in front of string, or if I write `::std::string name`, then it will compile fine.

This is of course a simplified example, I have many header files and not all of them show this behavior. I am not sure what can cause this, I thought that the compiler would always try the global namespace as well.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012 if this matters.

Comment: Does `AppNamespace` contain something called `std` for some reason?

Comment: Can you produce a http://sscce.org ?  There is something else going on you are not describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is of course a simplified example, I have many header files and not all of them show this behavior. I am not sure what can cause this, I thought that the compiler would always try the global namespace as well.

At some point you must have something like this:

```
namespace AppNamespace
{
  #include <string> // or #include "my_header" which in turn includes <string>

  class A
  {
    std::string name;
  };
}
```

The `#include` directive does not respect namespaces. You need to move them all out to the global namespace scope, or each (possibly nested) inclusion of a standard header will cause undefined behavior in the form of creating a nested namespace `std`.

Comment: I think this ended up to be this. I had a namespace somewhere that wasn't properly closed with curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "test_header.h"

int main() ...
```

The code compiles either way with your above example as a header.

Moving

> using namespace std;

below the header file (in my case test_header.h) will cause it to fail if I don't use std::string.

Is that the problem you are having?

Comment: I am also using VS2012 btw.

Comment: If I remove using namespace std; my header file (as you described) compiles.

Comment: you should not use `using namespace std;` anyways due since it can cause scoping issues and naming conflicts, just use the std:: prefix instead

Comment: It can, but for small test programmes or small projects you are working on alone, it is very convenient. Having to type std:: over and over again or using namespace std within functions and classes adds up. In this case he's not using it, so I guess I doesn't really matter. edit - the reason I used it here was to see if that was what was causing his problem.

Comment: I think it's ok to use it in implementation files, but never in header files as it will contaminate all other files where it is included

Comment: @Eric When I'm building header files, I do everything in that header until I'm happy with it, then split it out into a .cpp. I find I can work far quicker that way. For conveniece, I leave the using namespace std in global. It also makes me more aware of std function names, which I like to avoid repeating for clarity.

Comment: @David `using namespace std;` in a header is the worst possible way to access the `std` namespace. You have other options: You can selectively use types, like `using std::wstring;`, and you can place the using statement **inside** a class member implementation. `void X::foo() { using std::wstring; wstring str( L"bar" ); ... }`

Comment: @IInspectable Understood. I will continue to do it as I am working alone and it works well for me. When I finalize classes for reuse with other projects I can remove the global namespace std.